# Run javascript after fetch?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have index.php which contains a button and a div.
I have index.js as well as two other files: next.php and next.js.
Index.js adds an event listener to the button.  When it’s clicked, a fetch is called to load next.php into the div.
Next.php has another button.  The next.js adds an event listener to the next button that throws an alert.

The problem is, that no matter what I try, I cannot get the javascript to fire on the second button unless I add the event listener to the fetch call itself.

```
function getScreen(screenFileName) {
fetch('./files/php/' + screenFileName + '.php')
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(html => {
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
    document.getElementById('ScreenViewer').innerHTML = html;
    document.getElementById("btnBTN").addEventListener("click", function() {
        alert("text?");
    }, true);
  })
}

document.getElementById("btnPush").addEventListener("click", function() {
    getScreen("next");
}, true);
```

This code works but would become unruly in a large project extremely fast.  I had hoped that I could include a  tag at the end of the php file that got fetched and have it useable but that doesn’t work.  Adding the event listener code for the next button in script tags to the end of the next.php file also doesn’t work.
Is there anyway I can fetch a javascript file to append and run next.js after fetching next.php?

Why isn’t the script tag parsed in next.php?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try adding "onclick='next_button()' " attribute to your html button and have the js function of next.js already loaded in your index.php. The html onclick attribute is great because as soon as the browser sees your button, it will attach the event listener automatically. Alternatively if you can get your js source as a string from fetch, you can also eval() it to run it

Comment: Having onclick worked but I’d rather leave the html side as html only and not put javascript there.  Can you elaborate about the other method(s) you mentioned.  They seem to be more along the lines of what I like.  Eval()?  I’ll look into that.  Two fetch procedures wouldn’t be perfect but it would work.

Comment: Another way to get the next.js fire (without fetch but still with another request) is appending a script element to the DOM and giving it the src of your script after the main fetch.

Comment: How would one do that?

Comment: An example in vanilla javascript:
`let myscript = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("script"));
myscript.src = "next.js";`
(do this after your fetch request was successful)

Comment: Ooo...  that worked!  It’s not what I would call perfect but it’s certainly usable.  I think the parser should parse the <script> tag in the php but meh.  Umm... set that as an answer so I can click the green checkmark, please.  And thank you.